# 無相関検定をしたいのですがやりかたを教えてください

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_maize = pd.read_csv("PSD online data maize.csv", thousands=',')]
df_maize.corr()
```

相関係数の計算まではできましたが以下の検定でエラーが起きました

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
bs=df_maize['Beginning Stocks'].values
es=df_maize['Ending Stocks'].values
p_value=df_maize.corr[0]
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9b62ddc60036> in <module>
      1 bs=df_maize['Beginning Stocks'].values
      2 es=df_maize['Ending Stocks'].values
----> 3 p_value=df_maize.corr[0]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p-value` を求めるなら `scipy.stats.pearsonr()` を使うとよいかと。

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(5),
                   'B': [x**2 for x in range(5)],
                   'C': [x**3 for x in range(5)]})

p_value = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x,y)[1])
print(df)
print(p_value)
```

**dataframe**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 | 27 |
| 4 | 16 | 64 |

**p-value**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.00993072 | 0.0341674 |
| B | 0.00993072 | 1 | 0.00174922 |
| C | 0.0341674 | 0.00174922 | 1 |

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。p_value = df.corr(method=lambda x, y: pearsonr(x,y)[1])の[1]はどういう意味がありますか？

Comment: `pearsonr(x, y)` の戻り値(の実体)はリストなのですが、2番目の要素が p-value になっています。